# UniswapV3 Swap Router Sepolia Address

Tags: solidity, etherscan, uniswapv3, sepolia

Have been looking for UniswapV3's SwapRouter's deployed address on the Sepolia Test Network. For some reason the Unsiwap has't provided us with the Sepolia deployed addresses.

Can someone help me here.

In case anyone's looking the factory address on Seplia is:

0x0227628f3F023bb0B980b67D528571c95c6DaC1c

Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the list of deployed contracts of Uniswap contracts on different chains here: https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments

It is odd however that there is no Sepolia addresses added.

I tried sending a swap transaction through Uniswap UI and this is the address it used as a **router**: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x3fc91a3afd70395cd496c647d5a6cc9d4b2b7fad#code

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/v1.0.0/testnet-deploys.md

take a look here, maybe this helps

Comment: I think I found it here

https://sepolia.etherscan.io/token/0x1238536071e1c677a632429e3655c799b22cda52#code